# How to create a non ad-hoc hotspot connection on Windows XP?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking, hotspot, galaxy-s3

I want to share my cabled connection with a Samsung Galaxy S3 smartphone, which however **does not support** ad-hoc connections (at least if one does not tweak it). 
Is there some software to do this in Windows XP? All the programs I tried require Windows 7 or 8, as they rely on the new netsh commands (which are not available in XP).

I stress that I don't want to root my phone.

Comment: It is not possible to do this safely now that xp is long past its end of life.

Comment: Ok, so probably most (wise) people do not use XP any longer..
I just want to know if somebody faced this problem when using XP before its end of life :P

Comment: What are you trying to do? Share the internet connection from the computer to the phone so the phone uses the computer's data rather than its own? And you don't want to do it via [root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494)? Seems like an [android question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63700/reverse-tethering-android-galaxy-s3-to-windows-7-via-bluetooth) - maybe with [this tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether)

Comment: Exactly. It is OS-related, too, since Win 7 and 8 provide the needed features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a Lenovo smartphone (which now rests in electronic heaven, unfortunately) with which I wished to do the same.

This is known as **reverse tethering.**
The best known method of reverse tethering requires you to root your phone: do note, rooting voids your warranty.If your phone is already rooted, great! If not, here's the safest way to do it without harming your phone.

**PROCEDURE:**

1. Download the **Towelroot** app: https://towelroot.com/
   Install it on your phone. Open it and press the "Make it Ra1n" button. If it gives you a message that says that process was completed, you're rooted. Download Root Checker from Play Store and run it once to confirm rooting.
2. Download **Android Reverse Tethering on your PC**: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1371345
3. On your Galaxy, open **Settings > Developer Options**. **Turn on USB debugging**. Connect phone to PC via **USB**.
4. Open Android Reverse Tethering on your PC. Press **"Connect"**.

A Superuser permission request will come up on your phone screen. Press **"Accept"**. Now try to browse the web on your phone.

**TO USE THE GOOGLE PLAY STORE ON REVERSE TETHERING:**

1. Open Android Reverse Tethering on your PC again. Don't press the Connect button right now.
2. Press the "**Install hack (optional)" button**. Xposed Installer app should open on your phone's screen when you do this.
3. Install the "**Hack Connectivity Service**". Now, in Xposed Installer's main menu, select **Modules**, enable Hack Connectivity Service and restart your phone.
4. Restart your phone.
5. Now press the **"Connect"** button on the Android Reverse Tethering program open on your PC.

You do it as I said and it's guaranteed to work.

P.S. I used Android Reverse Tethering from a Windows XP PC.

**IF YOU ARE AFRAID TO ROOT YOUR DEVICE:** It's understandable, because I've seen forums full of horror stories where people bricked their phones.

But do note: **if you strictly want to do it on XP, forget it.** The other method requires Ubuntu, a free operating system. You can create a LiveUSB with persistence, so you can work on Ubuntu without installing it on your PC.

**Pre-requisites:**

- a Wi-Fi dongle
- a pen drive which you have prepared with a bootable ISO of Ubuntu (plenty of tutorials online if you are a newcomer, though I doubt you're one)
- (of course) an Internet connection.

  1. Start up Ubuntu. You can create a LiveUSB stick with persistence enabled to work on Ubuntu without installing it, so your Windows XP installation remains safe without any modding.
  2. Open **Terminal** and type this: `sudo apt-get install hostapd`
     Then this:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server hostapd
     ```
  3. Now type `sudo gedit` and copy the following details into it:

     ```
     interface=wlan0
     driver=nl80211
     ssid=YOUR_SSID_NAME
     hw_mode=g
     channel=11
     wpa=1
     wpa_passphrase=YOUR_PASSWORD
     wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
     wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
     wpa_ptk_rekey=600
     ```

Save this file in `/home/` directory with the name **hostapd.conf**

4. Open Terminal again and type this:

   ```
   sudo hostapd hostapd.conf
   ```

All you have to do now is simply connect your phone to the ad-hoc WiFi network you just created. Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but as I said I want to avoid rooting my phone..

Comment: @Mizar Answer modded for your convenience

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM does your Windows XP Box have?

Setup a VirtualBox, with a basic linux or bsd router OS.  eg Smoothwall, IPCop, Zeroshell, M0n0wall, pfSense.

Probably 256 or 512MB virtual RAM would be enough to run any of those distro, and link (bridge) your physical devices to the ones on your virtualized firewall.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP has always been bad at this type of thing. If you're really opposed to rooting your phone, you're gonna need to drop some cash.

Any usb wifi device with the `atheros` chipset will allow you host an access point in master mode. To find the one that will work for you, checkout `aircrack-ng` more specifically `airbase-ng` here http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airbase-ng

Here's a list of card/chips/devices that will work with airbase http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers